# Unrecognized VM option 'ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages'

Tags: java, junit

I'm new to java and I met this problem when I learnt about running junits testing in intelliJ. I changed run/debuug configurations templates for new projects->Junit->VM options to "-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages". Then when I ran the test file, it showed error message like :

Unrecognized VM option 'ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Could anyone help me figure out this problem? Thanks

Comment: you do _not_ need that option to run Junit tests, remove it.

Comment: What java version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The option `-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages` was introduced in Java 14 (https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/358), I suppose that you are trying to use this option in a previous version of Java.